# Using NumberRangeFilterBuilder for a slider controlled variable input?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I've been looking for a slider control in sheets where I can play with a variable input by moving the slider left or right. Within the following example:

```
A1 = Value | B1 = VAR | C1 = A1*B1
```

I want the B1 cell to be occupied by a number given by a slider that moves between 100 and 1000, with increments of 100. The slider itself preferably in another cell. I know this is possible, by documentation about [NumberRangeFilterBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/number-range-filter-builder)

Can you give me an example of the script and calling it with a specified range? I cannot seem to find any other documentation on the implementation nor can I make it work.

Comment: Charts service was typically used with Uiapp, which is deprecated now. You'd need to use [html](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls) and mix in the range data from spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you request, but in meanwhile it could perhaps help...

- **[copy of the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15uuNDJCPAiT-elGn1Riz7oxTDIefpU6MiOBLc4PN5UA/copy)**
- formula for 10x increments:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(ROW(INDIRECT("A100:A1000")), MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A100:A1000")),10)=0))
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: Appreciate the effort but it's not at all suitable for my needs

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Apps Script sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars) tutorial. You can create a slider in HTML, and put it in the sidebar, and have it modify your cell value.

Comment: This is "almost" a link only answer. Could you please elaborate briefly your answer?